# xquery - BFS and shortest path between two nodes

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a task. I must find shortest path between two nodes in XML using BFS. The XML is 'Romeo & Juliet' (you can find it here: [enter link description here](http://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/r_and_j.xml)).

I must find shortest paths between Juliet and others speakers. Nodes in graph should be speakers, edges - speech in which two speakers appear together. For example: if Juliet talk with X, distance will be 1. But if Juliet talk with X (but not with Y) and X talk with Y, distance is 2.

The result should looks like that (it's only example):

```
<speaker name="Romeo"><distance>1</distance></speaker>
<speaker name="Tybalt"><distance>3</distance></speaker>
<speaker name="Benvolio"><distance>2</distance></speaker>
...
```

I prepare same code, but i don't have idea on BFS:

```
declare function local:BFS($queue,$speakers,$visited,$step)
{
  let $u :=
    for $i in $queue
        for $w in local:neighbour($i)
          (..)

  return ($u)
};

declare function local:neighbour($person as xs:string)
{
let $file := "r_and_j.xml"

let $speakers :=
  distinct-values(doc($file)/PLAY/ACT/SCENE/SPEECH/SPEAKER)

let $sp-query := 

              for $y in $speakers

                where not($person=$y)
                return if(doc($file)/PLAY/ACT/SCENE[SPEECH[SPEAKER=$person] and SPEECH[SPEAKER=$y]])
                       then
                       $y
                       else ()


return $sp-query
};
```

Function 'neighbour' return nodes from neighbourhood (speakers who talk with person which is get from parametr).

Answer (score 1):

There was a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194711/search-a-path-between-two-graph-nodes-in-xquery) one month ago. Please read through the answer to understand why your nested `for` loops will not work the way you think they will.

For your specific task it would be more fitting to view each "round" of the [BFS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (processing of all nodes found after a specific number of steps) instead of using a simple queue. I would also extract the neighbors once in the beginning and store them in a more easily accessible form. Then the algorithm could look like this:

```
declare function local:round($n, $last-round, $out) {
  if(empty($last-round)) then (
    (: last round found no new persons, we are finished :)
    $out
  ) else (
    let $current-round :=
      (: iterate over all persons found in the last round :)
      fold-left($last-round, (), function($current, $speaker) {
        (: iterate over their neighbors :)
        fold-left(
          (: ignore persons found in previous rounds :)
          $persons[@name=$speaker/@name]/neighbor/@name[not(. = $out/@name)],
          $current,
          function($current2, $neighbor) {
            if($current2/speaker[@name = $neighbor]) then (
              (: person was already found this round, ignore :)
              $current2
            ) else (
              (: append newly found person to this round's output :)
              $current2,
              <speaker name="{$neighbor}"><distance>{$n}</distance></speaker>
            )
          })
      })
    return local:round($n + 1, $current-round, ($out, $last-round))
  )
};
```

The whole query can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/LeoWoerteler/ae998db0b3b1f08ef72f). It requires [XQuery 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/) and was tested with the newest version of [BaseX](http://basex.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet here would probably be to get away from XML and model your entities in a graph database like Jena. From there you can easily establish shortest paths through both number of joins and adding weights to your relationships.